# Nexmon not installing tools

Tags: android

I have recently installed nexmon on my s10... which was very hard now i want to install the tools but it doesn't work with the prebuild apk i found on the kali nethunter fdroid store. I am using magisk. I would realy enyoy help.

System specifigs:
Android-10
SM-G973F/DS
Magisk 26.1
SELinux Permissive
TWRP

I tried building the app myself from source on ubuntu 64bit
it didn't work i had multiple building problems
And i had some small problems while building nexmon but i think nexmon worked